# RestSharp and nancy authorization

Tags: wpf, security, restsharp, nancy

I am using WPF forms and RestSharp library to call Nancy web server.
But nancy has Form Authentication which work very well for Web Pages.

But how to handle it all in WPF Application ?

I can authenticate using WPF form, but I have to pass something in nest web calls..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it is working for webpages is that the browser keeps the auth cookie that Nancy generates.

What you can do is generate a token that you can then pass in the header with all the subsequent requests.Have a look at
[Nancy stateless authentication](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Stateless-Authentication) .

If you are using owin to host your api you can also use [Owin.StatelessAuth](https://github.com/jchannon/Owin.StatelessAuth).

Comment: But I wanna call this rest service both from WPF and web !

Comment: You still can , it is just that forms auth does not suit your setup so you need to use stateless auth. Look at [Angular stateless demo](http://blog.jonathanchannon.com/2014/05/07/introducing-owin-statelessauth-with-nancy-angular-demo/).